# postgres - pg_dump and pg_restore without roles

Tags: postgresql, restore, postgresql-9.3, pg-dump, pg-restore

I'm trying to restore a dump without having the appropriate roles on the receiving database.

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31469008/postgresql-backup-database-and-restore-on-different-owner) but also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17153008/import-postgres-database-without-roles), you need to have the `--no-owner` as an option, either in `pg_dump` or `pg_restore` or both.

I've used the following command line to create my dump:

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\pg_dump.exe" --no-owner -Ft --dbname=postgresql://avo******:AV0******?@127.0.0.1:5432/BI_DB > K:\BI\backup\sort\bck_%timestamp%.tar
```

The restoring line is as follows:

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\pg_restore.exe" --host localhost --port 5432 --username "postgres" --dbname "BI_TEST2" --no-password  --no-owner --role=postgres --exit-on-error --verbose "D:\D\avo\backup\bck_04042017_1410.tar"
```

As you can see, both have the `--no-owner` option but eventually, I have the error below:

[image]

What terribly bugs me is the log below:

```
pg_restore: [programme d'archivage (db)] Erreur pendant le traitement de la TOC (« PROCESSING TOC ») :
pg_restore: [programme d'archivage (db)] Erreur à partir de l'entrée TOC 2633 ; 0 0 ACL adm avo******
pg_restore: [programme d'archivage (db)] could not execute query: ERREUR:  role « avo****** Â» does not exist
```

Why does it say it needs a role even if the `--no-owner` was specified?

Did I miss something?

I'm running on Postgres 9.3

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The error occurs when `pg_restore` set the ACLs : you can use `--no-acl` to prevent `GRANT` commands.

With the `-Ft` option in `pg_dump`, you can skip roles and ACLs only in `pg_restore`. You can also edit the catalog with `--list` if you need more details.

Answer (score 24):

Using PostgreSQL 12.4:

```bash
$ pg_dump --help
...
-O, --no-owner               skip restoration of object ownership in
                             plain-text format
...
-x, --no-privileges          do not dump privileges (grant/revoke)
```

Here's an example:

```
$ pg_dump -O -x mydb_development | gzip > mydb-2020-09-22.bak.gz
```

Answer (score 5):

The following commands export data without mixing it with role or privilege data so that you can import it to any role you specify. Also, you can make pg_dump compress the data to a tar file for you.

```bash
pg_dump --format=t --blobs --verbose --no-privileges --no-owner \
--password --username mydbuser --database mydbname  \
--file "mydbname_dump_$(date +%Y%m%d).tar"
```

Or a shorter one for it that does the same thing

```
pg_dump -F t -bvxOW -U myuser -d mydbname  -f "mydbname_dump_$(date +%Y%m%d).tar"
```

To restore you will then use almost the same flags and also mention which role you want ownership to belong to.

```
pg_restore -vxOW --role=myuser2 -U myadminuser -d mydbname "mydbname_dump_$(date +%Y%m%d).tar"
```

Below is what all these flags mean and some more for additional options like compression level or format to output. You can find more by doing `pg_dump --help` or `pg_restore --help`:

```
General options:
  -f, --file=FILENAME          output file or directory name
  -F, --format=c|d|t|p         output file format (custom, directory, tar,
                               plain text (default))
  -v, --verbose                verbose mode
  -Z, --compress=0-9           compression level for compressed formats

Options controlling the output content:
  -b, --blobs                  include large objects in dump
  -O, --no-owner               skip restoration of object ownership in
                               plain-text format
  -x, --no-privileges          do not dump privileges (grant/revoke)

Connection options:
  -d, --dbname=DBNAME      database to dump
  -h, --host=HOSTNAME      database server host or socket directory
  -p, --port=PORT          database server port number
  -U, --username=NAME      connect as specified database user
  -w, --no-password        never prompt for password
  -W, --password           force password prompt (should happen automatically)
  --role=ROLENAME          do SET ROLE before dump
```

Comment: TAR format is not compressed.
> Output a tar-format archive suitable for input into pg_restore. The tar format is compatible with the directory format: extracting a tar-format archive produces a valid directory-format archive. However, the tar format does not support compression. Also, when using tar format the relative order of table data items cannot be changed during restore.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can restore a database backup into another database and at the same time create the privileges for another user without any prerequisites with regard to how `pg_dump` has been run by using the options

```
--dbname <new_database> --no-owner --role <new_user>
```

Do *not* use `--no-privileges`, as this would suppress all GRANTs during restore.